Correlation of a Specific Elliptic Curve with the Upper Bound of a Binomial Coefficient sum.
I was messing around in Desmos a while ago and tried to manually adjust an elliptic curve (where C is the adjustable) $$y^2 = x^3 - Cx + 1$$
to make it such that it cut the x axis at exactly 2 points (such that the little loop and the main curve were joined at exactly one point).
And after approximating C, I got the value as $1.8898815748423097$
Then, after wondering from where the number arose, I looked it up on Google, where I was met with this Mathstackexchange question about an upper bound limit of a sum and found out from there that the number is exactly $2$ raised to the power of $-2/3$ , times $3$.
I just wanted to know the correspondence between the two— is this simply a coincidence, or is there some deeper relation behind these two seemingly different things?

What you are asking for, where "the little loop and the main curve join at exactly one point", is for when the curve $y^2=x^3-Cx+1$ has a node.
For a curve in short Weierstrass form, say $E:y^2=x^3+a_4x+a_6$ we define the auxilliary quantities:
$$
\begin{align*}
b_4&=2a_4 \\
b_6&=4a_6 \\
c_4&=-24b_4 \\
c_6&=-216b_6 \\
\Delta&=-16(4a_4^2+27a_6^2)
\end{align*}
$$
Then it is a well-known result the $E$ has a node if and only its discriminant $\Delta=0$ and $c_4\ne 0$. For a reference see Joseph H. Silverman. The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. page 31.
In your case we are fixing $a_6=1$, leaving only $a_4=-C$ to be determined. We can easily see that $c_4=48C$ must be non-zero, therefore $C\ne 0$, and setting $\Delta=0$ you get that
$$
\begin{align*}
0=\Delta&=-16(4(-C)^3+27) \\
&=64C^3-432
\end{align*}
$$
Which solves to $C=3\cdot 2^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

I think they were not really asking for a solution, but asking why this value comes up in a completely different context. Still, this does show how the constant can be found algebraically, but the main question remains open!

@HackR.- This solution is exactly what you have from the necessary equation $y^2=(x-a)(x-b)^2 \text { where } a\lt b$ i gave in my comment below. The different context corresponds to a non-elliptic cubic with the equations $a+2b=0,\space 2ab+b^2=-C,\space ab^2=1$ from which $C=3\times 2^{-2/3}$.

Referencing what @HackR said, its true that I wanted to know how the value arose algebraically and it was interesting to see how it could be obtained by two different solutions, this one and the one Piquito gave below. Though I also wanted to know the correlation between the curve having a node and the other question I linked. It might be just a coincidence but it did leave me kind of intrigued.

COMMENT.-When, as you want to, the little loop and the main curve were joined at exactly one point you do not have anymore an elliptic curve because that point is a singularity so the cubic is rational (strophoids) and admits a rational parameterization $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ which is not possible in elliptic curves. The corresponding cartesian equations with the curve cut the x axis at exactly 2 points are
$$y^2=(x-a)(x-b)^2 \text { where } a\lt b$$ so you can calculate the value of your constant $C$.
